# Vuejs editing prop object property in child component

Tags: vue.js

I have been using Vue for a while but still do not have a clear understanding of the benefits related to this (probably controversial) question. I know it has been asked in different ways many times, but I can't find a clear answer.

As "Example 1", let's say I have a parent component that contains an `address` object, and it passes that address to a child `AddressForm` so it can be edited by the user, like this:

```
// Parent.vue

<template>
    <AddressForm :address="address" @submit="onSubmit"/>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data () {
        return {
            address: {}
        }
    },
    methods: {
        onSubmit() {
            console.log('Submit', this.address);
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Then, the child component looks like this, which directly manipulates the properties of the parent address object.
Here I am only showing an input for the `address.name` to keep things concise, but you can imagine there is a similar text input for any other properties of the address.

```
// AddressForm.vue

<template>
    <form @submit.prevent="onSubmit">
        <input v-model="address.name">
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            address: {
                type: Object,
                required: true,
            }
        },
        methods: {
            this.$emit('submit');
        }
    }
</script>
```

The issues here is that I am directly editing the `address` prop in the child. Of course I do not get any warnings from Vue about it because I am only editing a property of the `address` object, not actually mutating it by reassigning.

There are countless places where I can read about why this is not best practice, it's an anti-pattern, and it's a bad idea. You shouldn't alter props in child components.

Ok, but why? Can someone provide any type of real world use-case where the code above can lead to issues down the road?

When I read about the "proper" alternative ways to do things, I am even more confused because I don't see any real difference. Here's what I mean:

Let's call this "Example 2", where I now use v-model to enforce "proper" 2-way binding rather than editing the prop directly like I was in Example 1:

```
// Parent.vue

<template>
    <AddressForm v-model="address" @submit="onSubmit"/>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data () {
        return {
            address: {}
        }
    },
    methods: {
        onSubmit() {
            console.log('Submit', this.address);
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

```
// AddressForm.vue

<template>
    <form @submit.prevent="onSubmit">
        <input v-model="localValue.name">
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            value: {
                type: Object,
                required: true,
            }
        },
        computed: {
            localValue: {
                get: function() {
                    return this.value;
                }
                set: function(value) {
                    this.$emit('input', value);
                }
            }
        },
        methods: {
            this.$emit('submit');
        }
    }
</script>
```

What is the difference between Example 1 and Example 2? Aren't they doing, literally, exactly the same thing?

In Example 2, the computed property says that `localValue` is always equal to `value`. Meaning, they are the same exact object, just like they were in Example 1.

Further, as you type in the input, if you watch the events being fired in the Vue debugger, `AddressForm` never even emits the `input` events, presumably because `localValue` isn't actually being set, since it's just an object property that's being changed.

This again shows that Example 1 and Example 2 are doing the exact same thing. The object property is still being directly mutated within the child even though `v-model` is being used.

So, again, my question is, why is Example 1 considered bad practice? And how is Example 2 any different?

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow), manipulating a prop directly causes several issues:

- Makes app's data flow harder to understand
- Every time a parent component is updated, all props in the child component will be refreshed